# Oracle Loop - declaration

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, partition

I want to use LOOP to go trough all partitions in a table to change some data per partitions.
I am starting like:

```
BEGIN
FOR n in (here is the select statement which chooses the partition names)
LOOP
UPDATE table_name    
PARTITION (n)
SET
here are columns to change with new values;
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I get error ORA 02149 and ORA 06512 that partition does not exist.
Is it related to some declaration? How I should solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with a partition name? What benefit do you expect? Simply

```
update table_name set
  col1 = ...,
  col2 = ...
where condition_goes_here --> this condition will "determine" the partition
```

Comment: What I meant to say was: you shouldn't worry about the partition. Let Oracle handle that. Your task is to create a WHERE clause which will make sure that only desired rows are updated. Which partitions do they belong to? Doesn't matter (from your point of view), Oracle knows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execute immediate` and `user_tab_partitions` data dictionary view together as

```
Begin
  for c in ( select * 
               from user_tab_partitions p 
              where p.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
              order by p.partition_position )
  loop
    execute immediate 'update '||c.table_name||' partition('||c.partition_name||') 
                          set col1 = ''xYz'' ';
    commit;
  end loop;
End;
```